# Angular HttpModule map json to entity list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular

I have an angular 5 application which retrieves user events data form a REST API. See blow angular code:

**Service**

```
/** GET user events from the server */
  getCalendarEvents(): Observable<UserEvents[]> {
    return this.http.get<UserEvents[]>(this.apiUrl + '/user_events')
    .pipe(
      tap(items => console.log(items)),
      catchError(this.handleError('getEvents', []))
    );
  }
```

**Component**

```
userEventsList: UserEvents[] = [];

getCalendarEvents(): void {
    this.calendarService.getCalendarEvents()
      .subscribe(data => {
        // console.log(data[0].user.FullName);    
        this.userEventsList = data;
      });
  }
```

**UserEvents** interfaces:

```
export interface UserEvents {
    user: User;
    bookings: Event[];
}

export interface User{
    Id: string;
    FullName: string;
    Email: string;
}

export interface Event {
    Id: string;
    StartTime: string;
    EndTime: string;
    Description: string;
}
```

**API response**

```
[
    {
        "User": {
            "Id": "123abc",
            "FullName": "First Person",
            "Email": "first.person@example.com"
        },
        "Events": [
        {
            "Id": "eventId-1",
            "StartTime": "2018-01-01T00:00:00",
            "EndTime": "2018-01-01T00:00:00",
            "Description": "Event 1"
        },
        {
            "Id": "eventId-2",
            "StartTime": "2019-01-01T00:00:00",
            "EndTime": "2019-01-01T00:00:00",
            "Description": "Event 2"
        }]
    },
    {
        "User": {
            "Id": "user2",
            "FullName": "Second user",
            "Email": "second.user@example.com"
        },
        "Events": []
    },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

The problem is that the returned entity 'UserEvents[]' is not filled up. 
In the component when trying to access to the object user -> console.log(data[0].user.FullName), an error is produced indicating that it doesn't exist.

It seems that `HttpClient` module didn't manage to map correctly the entity.

In the angular guide for [httpclient module](https://angular.io/guide/http) it is explained how to specify the entity type in order to return plain entities. 
In my case it is a more complex entity formed by other entities and maybe that's the point?

Am I missing anything? Do I have it to map the entity by myself?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `UserEvents` interface and the structure of api response is not similar. Is it the same api response you find after logging the subscribe arrow function in your component?

Comment: And how has the `UserEvents` interface to be in order to let angular map correctly the json data?

Comment: okey try to change `userEventsList` type to `any[]` and see what happens

Comment: @Ashraful Islam, the same happens. The whole json object list is passed back directly to the component instead of mapping it to UserEvents

Comment: Try to log `data` in getCalendarEvents() subscribe method and see if you get the correct data. I think the data is not coming properly in `getCalendarEvents` subscribe method

Comment: The data received within the subscribe method is the raw data provided by the API, not a list of objects of type `UserEvents`

Comment: Try renaming your property names in the API response to match your `UserEvent` interface property names.  The API response is returning a property called `Events` instead of `bookings`.  The property names may have to be returned in lowercase as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getCalendarEvents(): Observable<UserEvents[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/user_events')
    .map((result:any=>{  //We transform the response
        return result.map((item: any) => {  //with each element
                        //your item has User and Events
                        //Your UserEvent interface has "user" and "booking"
              return
              {
                   user:item.User,
                   bookings:item.Events
              }
          })
       }).do(result=>
      {
             //just only for check, after remove .do
            console.log(result)
      })
      .catchError(this.handleError('getEvents', []))
    );
  }
```

look that we need two map, one to transform the Observable, and one to transform each element of observable

Comment: you are completely right! I implemented what you pointed out and it is working perfectly ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using pipe in api response.

Try to use map instead of pipe

```
getCalendarEvents(): Observable<UserEvents[]> {
  return this.http.get<UserEvents[]>(this.apiUrl + '/user_events')
    .map(res => res.json()).catch(err => this.handleError());
}
```

Comment: The way you specified is used when using the angular `Http` module instead of using the `HttpClient` module (which I am using). Am I wrong??

Comment: When I put '.map(res => res.json());' a typescript error is displayed indicating the following: "The property 'json' does not exist on type 'UserEvents'"

Comment: did you import map ? `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: Yes I did.  `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: Try removing the `UserEvents[]` type from http get method

Comment: @Alvykun this is correct; Ashraful Answer assume Http instead of HttpClient.HttpClient does not requires res.json() on the result.